# writing my own patent to an idea I developed at my work

Tags: ownership, workplace

I had an idea when working in previous job that I also come to implement it at my workplace. The workplace didn't want to issue this patent since it is not the main field in which the company is doing business.

I already moved to a new job and thinking of issuing the patent on my own. Can I do it? will it consider to be my patent?

Thank you

Comment: This is going to depend almost entirely on your employment contract — whether you were employed as "work for hire" or some other arrangement — which varies by jurisdiction and who is designated as the owner of any work you create. Since this has little to do with patents or the patent process, I suggest taking this to our [Law site](https://law.stackexchange.com). They will need a lot more detail about your situation, but non-patent IP issues are outside the scope of *this* site. Sorry about the confusion. Good luck!

Comment: Ask your original employer for permission first.

Comment: I don't think you actually need to ask permission, *if you invented the process*, but you should review the contract you signed with them, because it may include language regarding this.  Also, if it's been over a year since it first became public (implemented without secrecy) the grace period for filing may have expired.